# Using returnObject with @PreAuthorize in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, annotations

Can we use the `returnObject` built-in name to access the return value of a method in `@PreAuthorize` annotation? I read in the spring security documentation that we **can** use it with `@PostAuthorize`.

```
-    @PreAuthorize("returnObject?.tila == T(fi.vm.sade.eperusteet.domain.PerusteTila).VALMIS or hasPermission(#id, 'perusteenosa', 'LUKU')")
+    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#id, 'perusteenosa', 'LUKU')")
     PerusteenOsaDto.Laaja getVersio(@P("id") final Long id, final Integer versioId);
```

Comment: `@PreAuthorize` is executed before the annotated method is invoked.  Since the method has not been invoked yet, `returnObject` does not make sense.  So, to answer your question, no, `returnObject` is not available to `@PreAuthorize`.

Comment: so will the returnObject contain null here? I am trying to understand how it will behave.

Comment: `returnObject` variable is not defined for `@PreAuthorize` so it does not make sense to say that its value is `null` when `@PreAuthorize` is executed.  Any usage of `returnObject` with `@PreAuthorize` is therefore an invalid expression and will evaluate to `false`.